# Extracting fasta sequences in list files order

Tags: python, file-io, biopython

I need to extract some fasta sequences from "goodProteins.fasta" file (first input) with id list files present in separate folder (second input).

The format of the fasta sequence file is:

```
>1_12256
FSKVJLKDFJFDAKJQWERTYU......
>1_12257
SKJFHKDAJHLQWERTYGFDFHU......
>1_12258
QWERTYUHKDJKDJOKK......
>1_12259
DJHFDSQWERTYUHKDJKDJOKK......
>1_12260
ADKKHDFHJQWERTYUHKDJKDJOKK......
```

and the format of one of the id file is:

```
1_12258
1_12256
1_12257
```

I'm using the following script:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import glob

def process(wanted_file, result_file):
    fasta_file = "goodProteins.fasta" # First input (Fasta sequence)

    wanted = set()
    with open(wanted_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line != "":
                wanted.add(line)

    fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open(fasta_file),'fasta')
    with open(result_file, "w") as f:
        for seq in fasta_sequences:
            if seq.id in wanted:
                SeqIO.write([seq], f, "fasta")

listFilesArr = glob.glob("My_folder\*txt") # takes all .txt files as
                                           # Second input in My_folder
for wanted_file in listFilesArr:
    result_file = wanted_file[0:-4] + ".fasta"
    process(wanted_file, result_file)
```

It should extract fasta sequence based on the information and order list in the id file and the desired output would be:

```
>1_12258
QWERTYUHKDJKDJOKK......
>1_12256
FSKVJLKDFJFDAKJQWERTYU......
>1_12257
SKJFHKDAJHLQWERTYGFDFHU......
```

but I get:

```
>1_12256
FSKVJLKDFJFDAKJQWERTYU......
>1_12257
SKJFHKDAJHLQWERTYGFDFHU......
>1_12258
QWERTYUHKDJKDJOKK......
```

That is, in my final output I get the header sorted according to their lower values, but I want them in exactly the same order as described in the list files. I'm not sure how to do it...please help.

Comment: The indenting of the code in your question is messed up. Do you mean that you want the sequence id order in each `result_file` to be the same they are in the corresponding `wanted_file` being processed?

Comment: How big is the "goodProteins.fasta" file?

Comment: yes exactly .. I want sequence id order in each result_file to be the same they are in the corresponding wanted_file.. and the goodProteins.fasta file is big .. aroung 50-60 mb

Comment: Actually that's not that big by today's standards...and I think I know the cause of the your problem (and maybe a solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the root cause of the ordering problem is because `wanted` is a `set` which are unordered. Since you want the sequence ids in the `wanted_file`s to determine the ordering, you'd need to store them in something else that preserves order, like a list.

Alternatively, you can just process each line of the `wanted_file` as it's read. A problem with that approach is it would require you to potentially read through the "goodProteins.fasta" file many times — perhaps once for each line of the `wanted_file` if its contents aren't in a sorted order.

To avoid that, the entire file can be read in to a memory-resident dictionary whose keys are the sequence ids once using the `SeqIO.to_dict()` function, and then reused for each `wanted_file`. You say the file is 50-60 MB, but that isn't too much for most of today's hardware.

Anyway, here's code that attempts to do this. To avoid global variables there's a `Process` class that reads in the "goodProteins.fasta" file and converts it into a dictionary when an instance of it is created. Instances are callable and reusable, meaning that the same process object can be used with each of the `wanted_file`s without repeatedly reading the sequences file.

Note that the code is untested because I don't have the data files or the `Bio` module installed on my system — but hopefully it's close enough to help.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import glob

class Process(object):
    def __init__(self, fasta_file_name):
        # read entire fasta file into memory as a dictionary indexed by ID
        with open(fasta_file_name, "rU") as fasta_file:
            self.fasta_sequences = SeqIO.to_dict(
                                        SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, 'fasta'))

    def __call__(self, wanted_file_name, results_file_name):
        with open(wanted_file_name, "rU") as wanted, \
             open(results_file_name, "w") as results:
            for seq_id in (line.strip() for line in wanted):
                if seq_id:
                    SeqIO.write(self.fasta_sequences[seq_id], results, "fasta")

process = Process("goodProteins.fasta")  # create process object

# process each wanted file using it
for wanted_file_name in glob.glob(r"My_folder\*.txt"):
    results_file_name = wanted_file_name[:-4] + ".fasta"
    process(wanted_file_name, results_file_name)
```